# Unable to run docker application using docker-compose - Shows NoClassDefFoundError: io/dropwizard/Application

Tags: java, docker, dropwizard

My Dockerfile is as below, I created docker image using docker build command. But when I run docker-compose up command, I get error saying "NoClassDefFoundError: io/dropwizard/Application"

```
//Dockerfile
FROM amazoncorretto:11
MAINTAINER SJ
RUN mkdir -p /opt/application

WORKDIR /opt/application

ADD app/build/libs/app.jar app.jar
ADD app/configuration.yml configuration.yml

ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-jar", "app.jar"]
CMD ["server", "configuration.yml"]


//docker-compose.yml
version: '2.1'

networks:
  default:
    name: apptests
    driver: bridge

services:
  apptest:
    image: apptest/apptest
    container_name: apptest
    environment:
      - SERVICES=s3
    ports:
          - "8056:8081"
```

Error:

C:\MyApp>docker-compose up
Starting apptest ... done                                                                                Attaching to apptest
apptest | Error: Could not find or load main class com.main.application.TestApplication
apptest | Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/dropwizard/Application
apptest exited with code 1

Comment: You need to create an uber/shadow jar that includes the dropwizard libraries. Look into using the jib-gradle-plugin the Jib dropwizard example